# MVVMCross Spinner - SelectedItem not working?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, spinner, mvvmcross

I built a MvxBindableSpinner into my Android-Application:

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView             
      android:text="Mandant:"
      android:width="0px"
      android:layout_weight=".22" />
      <cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableSpinner
        android:layout_weight=".78"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/mandantlistitem_dropdown"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mandantlistitem"
        local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Mandanten'},'SelectedItem':{'Path':'SelectedMandant','Mode':'TwoWay'}}"/>
</TableRow>
```

The MandantClass is simple:

```
//Class
public class Mandant
{
    //Properties

    public string MandantBezeichnung { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is, that the SelectedItem isn't working.. its alway "null", whatever I choose.. The Property on The ViewModel for the SelectedItem looks like this:

```
    private string selectedMandant;
    public string SelectedMandant
    {
        get { return selectedMandant; }
        set { selectedMandant = value; FirePropertyChanged(() => SelectedMandant); }
    }
```

I tried everything, but can't get it work.. It compiles fine and no errormessages.. but its always null.. Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: one other thing... there are abbreviations available if you need them - so `cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableSpinner` can be written `Mvx.MvxBindableSpinner` - hope that helps

Comment: thank you very much for this tip, And I was able to solve the problem

Comment: When you get a second it might be nice to say how :) When someone else hits the same problem and finds this question, then they'll be interested :)

Comment: The Problem was very stupid.. I was using a List<Mandant> for the SpinnerBinding, but for the SelectedItem I was using a string, like u said, that was the 5th thing:`e.g. is your selectedItem a string but should be a Mandant?`.. But the binding trace level is also a nice thing to know.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I can suggest about how to debug/fix this.

---

First, can you set the binding trace level to Diagnostic - somewhere in your code call:

```
 MvxBindingTrace.TraceBindingLevel = MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic;
```

Does this reveal any more information about what is failing?

---

Second, if you are linking to the source code then try setting a breakpoint and/or adding some additional trace inside `_spinner_ItemSelected` in [MvxSpinnerSelectedItemBinding](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxSpinnerSelectedItemBinding.cs) - is this binding event being fired? Is it succeeding all the way through to the `FireValueChanged` call?

Depending on what that reveals, then try other debug steps like maybe tracing in [MvxBindableSpinner.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBindableSpinner.cs).

---

Third... can you try comparing to an existing sample - I think the Spinner idea came from https://github.com/Zoldeper/Blooor/ originally - so maybe take a look at something like [ProductEditView.axml](https://github.com/Zoldeper/Blooor/blob/master/Ahwa.Attila.Core.UI/Resources/Layout/ProductEditView.axml)

Does that code work? If so, can you spot the difference.

**Warning**: the code may have changed since that Blooor sample was written

---

Finally... and this is just a hunch... can you post a bit more of your ViewModel here? I'm wondering if you have a type mismatch going on... e.g. is your selectedItem a string but should be a Mandant?

---

If this is a bug in MvvmCross, then 'sorry' and please report it as an issue - on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues - preferably with a reproducible sample.